# DataGridViewCell Get the cell value next to the selected cell

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a DataGridView table with two columns (`id` and `Description`). When the user selects a cell which is in the description column, I want to be able to get the `id` value which is next to the cell on the left.

Here is what I have so far:

```
    dataGridView1.CellClick += (s, e) =>
        {
            int id;
            DataGridViewCell cell = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0];

            //Instead of this, what do I put to get the ID column?
            if (cell.ColumnIndex == 0)
                id = Convert.ToInt32(cell.Value);
            else 
                return;

            string[] data = UnitData[id];

            txtNum.Text = id.ToString();
            txtName.Text = data[0];
            txtDesc.Text = data[1];
        };
```

I want to be able to check if the column selected is description, if it is, get the cell next to it.

How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (IsDescriptionColumnIndex)            
{ 
  //Next
  dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[1, e.rowIndex];
}
```